# How to know if an Android App stores data on SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, android

This is a research question. I want to know if an Android application stores any data on SD Card. By installing and looking at the directories on SD Card, I know whether an app stores data on SD Card. But, is there an automatic way or tool to know this? Additionally, do you know in which directory the data is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Look in Android Configuration menu, Application Management, and select the application. It will tell you if SD card storage is used or not and how much.

Comment: How do you know under which directory it is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Cedric Simon is correct, but you can view apps data on the sdcard by navigating to the "android" folder on your sdcard, that is where a few apps save there data but apps can save in any location on your sd card and the folder containing data usually has a "." in front off the name to hide the folder from view, for example /sdcard/example (Un-hidden) and /sdcard/.example (Hidden), there is an option to show hidden files/folders on most file explorers.

Comment: data can be stored in any folder on SD card, not only just "android" folder.